# how to display dynamically generated textviews in paragraph style

Tags: android, textview

I am implementing view containing multiple textviews which are clickable and generated dynamically. I want to show them in paragraph style. Here is my code. Sorry if I am mistaking.

Here is what I have Done:

```
 private void init() {

    //int strLength=arrayList.size();
    arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("Name");
    arrayList.add("Address");
    arrayList.add("obj");
    arrayList.add("age");
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
            int x=10;
    int y=30;
    for (int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {
        String str=arrayList.get(i).toString();
        tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setId(i);
        tv.setText(str);
        tv.setTextSize(24);
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv.setClickable(true);
        tv.setFocusable(true);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if(arrayList.get(i).equals("Name")){
            y=y+10;
            x=60;
        }
        else
        {
            x=x+arrayList.size()+60;
        }
        if(i>0){
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF, i);

        }
        tv.setPadding(x+20, y,0,0);
        tv.setEms(25);
        tv.setWidth(80);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);

        rl.addView(tv, params);
        int x1=rl.getWidth();
        rl.getLayoutParams();
        Log.e("x===",String.format("%d",x1));
        Log.e("x===",String.format("%d",x));
    }


}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is code for dynamically generated textviews.But as per this code, textviews gets cut horizontally. As per requirement textviews appear at last position of layout should append to next line. Help for these.

Comment: Use `ScrollView` if your `Layout` gets cut at the last position. Post a screenshot to be more specific.

Comment: @Krrishnaaaa- I don't want to use ScrollView instead of that I want to append last textview to next line.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should use the

android:inputType = "textMultiLine"

PS : android:singLine = "true/fals" is now Deprecated and you have to use  android:inputType

Comment: @User123- android:inputType = "textMultiLine" is property for textview but requirement is for layout. Thanks.